# Funciones en el Controller

Tags: laravel, funciones, controller

Buen día, quiero agregar una funciones dentro de un controller y no me esta respetando un `if`.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $tipo = $request->get('tipo');
    $profe = $request->get('profesional');
    $dia = $request->get('dia');

    $ct =$this->cantturno($tipo,$profe,$dia); //devuelve 0
    $st =$this->sobreturno($profe); // devuelve 20
    
    //dd($ct ,$st); //tengo 0 y 20

    if ( $ct <= $st) { // **Esta validacion no la respeta.**
        guardo en el base
    } else { //no guardo nada
     return redirect('/turno');
    }
}   
    
private function sobreturno($profe)
{       
    $cant=DB::select("select sobreturno from profesionales where id=?",array($profe));

    return $cant;
}                          

 

private function cantturno($tipo,$profe,$dia)
{
    $cant = DB::select('Select count(*) cant
                            From turnos 
                            Where profesional = ?
                            And dia = ?
                            And paciente is not null 
                            And Tipo=?',array($profe,$dia,$tipo));
    
    return $cant;
}
```

¿Pueden tirarme alguna punta que me ayude? Simplifiqué las funciones para hacer la pregunta mas simple.
Muchas gracias.

Comment: Como compruebas que no respeta la condición? Si pones `if ( $ct <= $st) { return "{$ct} es <= que {$st}"; } else { return "{$ct} <= que {$st} es falso"; }` que te devuelve?

Comment: Hago esto if ( $ct <= $st) 
        { dd($ct ,$st);} 
        else 
        { dd($ct ,$st);} y siempre va por falso, aunque de vuelta la condicion. Si harcodeo los numero 0 <= 20 Si anda.  Compara bien por Integer o hay que formatearlo?

Comment: ¿Pero con eso como sabés que va a verdadero o falso si tenés lo mismo `dd($ct ,$st)` en los dos casos? Lo que te pregunté en el comentario anterior es con propósito de debuguear.

Comment: Es que tu prueba me da erro de array
ErrorException
Array to string conversion

Comment: probé asi intval($st) <= intval($ct)  y tampoco

  if ( intval($st) <= intval($ct)) 
        { //return "verdadero"; 
            dd($st ,$ct,'v');} 
        else 
        { //return "falso"; 
            dd($ct ,$st,'f');}  siempre sale por verdadero aunque de vuelta la condicion

Comment: @JuanManuelFerrero ese error de convertion es por que estás tratando por ejemplo de imprimir un array como si de un string se tratara

Comment: Entonces probablemente tengas un array y no un integer en alguna o ambas variables. Haz el dump por separado: `dump($st); dump($ct);` para ver que tienes realmente en cada variable, o `dump( gettype($st) ); dump( gettype($ct) );`

Comment: Esto me muestra :array:1 [▼
  0 => {#359 ▼
    +"sobreturno": 20
  }
]
array:1 [▼
  0 => {#1459 ▼
    +"cant": 0
  }
]
Es porque tengo el string delante del valor no?  como traigo solo el valor?

Comment: Ah, ok. Entonces estás comparando dos arrays y no dos enteros. Para que quede más limpio, creo que tendrías que hacer que las funciones te devuelvan el valor de los elementos correspondientes (0 y 20) en vez de esos arrays.

Comment: Ahi edite la consulta , para poner las funciones completas., Como devuelvo el valor solamente.. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como venimos hablando en los comentarios, tus funciones están devolviendo arrays y no integers, como los que pretendes comparar:

```
dump($st);
```

> array:1 [▼ 0 => {#359 ▼ +"sobreturno": 20 } ]

```
dump($ct);
```

> array:1 [▼ 0 => {#1459 ▼ +"cant": 0 } ]

Para que el código quede más limpio, creo que tendrías que hacer que las funciones te devuelvan el valor de los elementos correspondientes (0 y 20) en vez de esos arrays.

Una opción sería siguiendo con DB Query builder (paso tus expresiones raw a una sintaxis equivalente, pero a la "manera laravel query builder")

En el caso de la función `sobreturno` accediendo a la propiedad que corresponde a la columna seleccionada. Como la consulta te devolverá un objeto stdClass, puedes acceder a la propiedad `sobreturno` de esta manera `$cant->sobreturno`. Pero ten en cuenta que la consulta también te puede devolver null, por lo tanto puedes "cubrirte" de una posible excepción con `$cant->sobreturno ?? 0`:

```
private function sobreturno($profe)
{       
    //$cant=DB::select("select sobreturno from profesionales where id=?",array($profe));
    $cant = DB::table('profesionales')
        ->where('id', $profe)
        ->select('sobreturno')
        ->first();

    return $cant->sobreturno ?? 0;
}
```

Para el caso de la función `cantturno`, si ejecutas la consulta con `count()`, ya te aseguras que te devolverá un integer:

```
private function cantturno($tipo,$profe,$dia)
{
    /*
    $cant = DB::select('Select count(*) cant
                            From turnos 
                            Where profesional = ?
                            And dia = ?
                            And paciente is not null 
                            And Tipo=?',array($profe,$dia,$tipo));
    */
    $cant = DB::table('turnos')
        ->where('profesional', $profe)
        ->where('dia', $dia)
        ->where('Tipo', $tipo)
        ->whereNotNull('paciente')
        ->count();
    return $cant;
}
```

De todas maneras te sugiero que implementes [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent), el ORM de Laravel, pues una vez que le tomes la mano, te podrías facilitar las cosas, sobre todo si en el futuro piensas trabajar con relaciones.

Referencias:
[Database: Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries).
[Database: Query Builder Basic Where Clauses](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#basic-where-clauses).
[Database: Query Builder Retrieving A Single Row / Column From A Table](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#retrieving-a-single-row-column-from-a-table).
[Database: Query Builder Aggregates](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#aggregates).

Comment: Excelente. mil gracias